# how correctly display nanotime to second conversion

Tags: java, nanotime

I have a BFS algorithm to solve the 8-Puzzle, and one of the project requirements is to output the amount of time it takes to find the shallowest solution.

I am using `System.nanoTime()` to keep track of the applications run time because it solves the majority of the given puzzles in well under a second.

The problem i am having is whem i convert my `nanoTime` to seconds, it displays in a weird format.

the following code is used:

```
final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

//algorithm code removed for simplicity this all functions correctly


final long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
final double seconds = ((double)duration / 1000000000);
System.out.println("Nano time total: " + duration);
System.out.println("solution Time : " + seconds + " Seconds");
```

This produces the output:

```
 Nano time total: 916110
 solution time : 9.1611E-4 Seconds
```

I have also tried using floats to represent the values.

is anybody able to provide a better way to convert/display, maybe use a format output statement?

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: 9.1611E-4 is a valid way of representing a number. It's just scientific notation.

Comment: There are a lot of questions on formatting doubles. You could go look them up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you need: DecimalFormat

```
System.out.println("solution Time : " + new DecimalFormat("#.##########").format(seconds) + " Seconds");
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know there was a method like this out there. Im going to spend a bit of time looking round the API now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.format("solution Time : %f Seconds", seconds);
```

for the classic, non-exponential floating point number.